# Query for lowest voted accepted answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, data-explorer

Due to recent events I am curious - could someone create a data-explorer query that shows the `N` lowest-voted accepted answers?

My weak SQL-foo didn't get me to filtering posts for accepted answers ...

Comment: I'm curious to know what the "recent events" might be.

Comment: @Shawn: As do i... Completely forgot it in the meantime ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6295

Comment: Thank you. Had to [save it](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/289/lowest-voted-accepted-answers) with a name to favourite :)

Comment: I think this is a broken link now.

Comment: @solvingPuzzles: Fixed the link.

Comment: +1 Even it is link only answer :)